# how to resolve dependency problems on ubuntu parsec?

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, raspberry-pi4

I recently bought a raspberry pi to be able to test the Ubuntu OS. After several failures due to my limited knowledge of ubuntu, I finally succeeded. I also wanted to be able to access it from my fixed computer, so I first turned to TeamViewer but I didn't manage to install it. So I decided to download Parsec .deb file in order to install it. Unfortunately when I run the command "sudo dpkg -i parsec-linux.deb" I get errors. These tell me that there are dependency issues with multiple files. How do I go about resolving these errors?

errors : dependency problems prevent configuration of parsec:amd64
parsec:amd64 depends on libc6
parsec:amd64 depends on libgcc1
parsec:amd64 depends on libgl1
parsec:amd64 depends on libsm6
parsec:amd64 depends on libstdc++6
parsec:amd64 depends on libx11-6
parsec:amd64 depends on libxxf86vm1

Comment: You need to download the right Parsec deb file.  Pi is ARM not AMD64